# How do I reach a container through the host's hostname from another container?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm running docker 20.10 and docker-compose 1.29.2 on Centos 7.

I have two containers (bitbucket and jenkins) running on `myhost` using docker-compose.  I'm using the default `bridge` network.  The following are the hosts names and services:

```
host        : service/port   : container/host port mapping
myhost      : apache/80      : <na>
bitbucket   : bitbucket/7990 : 7990:7990
jenkins     : jenkins/8083   : 8083:8083
workstation : <na>           : <na>
```

From `workstation`, I get results from `curl myhost:80` and I get results from `curl myhost:7990`.

From `jenkins` I get results from `curl bitbucket:7990` and `curl myhost:80` but the problem is I **DO NOT** from `curl myhost:7990`.

I need to be able to reach a submodule from `jenkins` that is in `bitbucket`, and I want the `.gitmodules` file to reference the same submodule URL: `myhost:7990/scm/project/repo`.

I don't have any special network configuration on `myhost`.  I tried adding 7990 to the `docker` zone (firewall-cmd), but that did not help.

It seems like it is *almost* working.  What is the problem and solution here?

Thank you!

Comment: try by `link`: https://docs.docker.com/network/links/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the problem and solution here?

try by adding [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in your docker-compose's service by which It will link two different `containers` from each other.

- Links allow you to define extra aliases by which a service is reachable from another service.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the private IP of the container. If they are in the same network, it should work.

```
docker inspect <container ID> | grep -w -m1 "IPAddress"

<private IP>:7990/scm/project/repo
```